# Laravel event broadcasting not working with Pusher, event not being received on front-end

Tags: laravel, websocket, pusher, laravel-echo

I've created a chat app, which is working fine on my localhost, but on production event is not being broadcast. I have used a handle to see if event is working as expected but i think it isn't.

```
class MessageSent implements ShouldBroadcast
   {
       use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

       public $message, $participantId;

       /**
        * Create a new event instance.
        *
        * @return void
        */
       public function __construct($message, $participantId)
       {
           $this->message = $message;
           $this->participantId = $participantId;
       }

       public function handle() {
           dd('Hello WOrld');
       }

       /**
        * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
        *
        * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
        */
        public function broadcastOn()
         {
           return new PrivateChannel('chat.'
           .$this->message->room->id
          );
         }
        }
```

Where I'm broadcasting my event in controller

```
public function addMessage(Request $request)
       {
           $roomId = $request->input('roomId');
           $participantId = $request->input('participantId');
           if (empty($roomId)) {
               $room = ChatRoom::create(['type' => 'chat']);
               $roomId = $room->id;
               ChatRoomUserRelation::create(
                   [
                       'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
                       'room_id' => $roomId
                   ]
               );
                ChatRoomUserRelation::create(
                   [
                       'user_id' => $participantId,
                       'room_id' => $roomId
                   ]
               );
           }
           $userId = Auth::user()->id;
           $message = $request->input('message');
           $media = [];
           $i = 0;
           while ($request->file('media' . $i) !== null) {
               if (
                   $request->file('media' . $i)->move(
                       base_path('public/images/posts/'),
                       $request->file('media' . $i)->getClientOriginalName()
                   )
               ) {
                $media[] = $request->file('media' . $i)->getClientOriginalName();
               }
               $i++;
           }
           $newMessage = Chat::create([
               'messaged_by' => $userId,
               'message' => $message,
               'media' => json_encode($media)
           ]);

           ChatRoomRelation::create([
               'chat_id' => $newMessage->id,
               'room_id' => $roomId
           ]);

           $newMessage = $newMessage->load(['user', 'room', 'room.participant']);
           broadcast(new MessageSent($newMessage, $participantId));
           broadcast(new MessageRecieved($newMessage));
           return $newMessage;
       }
```

Broadcasting.php

```
<?php

      return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Broadcaster
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default broadcaster that will be used by the
    | framework when an event needs to be broadcast. You may set this to
    | any of the connections defined in the "connections" array below.
    |
    | Supported: "pusher", "ably", "redis", "log", "null"
    |
    */

     'default' => env('BROADCAST_DRIVER', 'null'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Broadcast Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define all of the broadcast connections that will be used
    | to broadcast events to other systems or over websockets. Samples of
    | each available type of connection are provided inside this array.
    |
    */

     'host' => env('PUSHER_HOST') ?: 'api-'.env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER', 'mt1').'.pusher.com',
                 'port' => env('PUSHER_PORT', 443),
                 'scheme' => env('PUSHER_SCHEME', 'https'),

    'connections' => [

        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'encrypted' => true,
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => 6001,
                'scheme' => 'http',
                'curl_options' => [
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
                ]
            ],
            'client_options' => [
                // Guzzle client options: https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html
            ],
        ],

        'ably' => [
            'driver' => 'ably',
            'key' => env('ABLY_KEY'),
        ],

        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
        ],

        'log' => [
            'driver' => 'log',
        ],

        'null' => [
            'driver' => 'null',
        ],

       ],

       ];
```

bootstrap.js

```
     import _ from 'lodash';
     import 'bootstrap';

    /**
    * We'll load the axios HTTP library which allows us to easily issue requests
    * to our Laravel back-end. This library automatically handles sending the
    * CSRF token as a header based on the value of the "XSRF" token cookie.
    */

    import axios from 'axios';
    window.axios = axios;

    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

    /**
    * Echo exposes an expressive API for subscribing to channels and listening
    * for events that are broadcast by Laravel. Echo and event broadcasting
    * allows your team to easily build robust real-time web applications.
    */

    import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

    import Pusher from 'pusher-js';
    window.Pusher = Pusher;

     window.Echo = new Echo({
       broadcaster: 'pusher',
       key: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
     wsHost: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_HOST ?? `ws-${import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}.pusher.com`,
     wsPort: 6001,
     wssPort: 6001,
     cluster:import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,//added this line
     forceTLS: false,
     disableStats: true,
     enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
      });
```

A function in my component to listen broadcasted event

```
joinChatChannel() {
            this.chatChannel = window.Echo.private(`chat.${this.activeRoomId}`)
            //listening for channel whisper
            this.chatChannel.listenForWhisper('typing', user => {
                this.placeholder = user.first_name + ' is typing...'
                if (this.typingTimer) {
                    clearTimeout(this.typingTimer);
                }
                this.typingTimer = setTimeout(() => {
                    this.placeholder = '';
                }, 500);
            })
            //listening which gets fired on message sent
            this.chatChannel.listen('MessageSent', (e) => {
                this.roomChats.push(e.message);
                if (this.activeRoomId == 0) {
                    this.rooms.push(e.message.room);
                    this.activeRoomId = e.message.room.id;
                }
            })
        }
```

Project is deployed on VPS, and made live on an ip, but websocket configured to run on localhost, same scenario is wokring on on my own pc, but not in VPS, let me know If I'm missing something here or you may require to see any file, please help me I've tried so many things through but nothing worked, I know this question might be duplicated but issue seems different.

[developer network table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoLac.png)

I have tried to reinstall my operating system, reinstall laravel, reinstall all the dependencies, checked out the websocket logs, there was no broadcasted event listed, checked websocket dashboard stats.

Comment: Check your `.env` file if the `BROADCAST_DRIVER` is equal to `pusher`

Comment: BROADCAST_DIVER is pusher, because I'm using pusher, does it suppose to be something else?